# creating a stored procedure in Oracle complain about invalid variable declaration

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When I try to create a stored procedure like this:

```
create or replace
procedure USR_Trial
( auth out usrr.DEPARTMENT 
)
AS
BEGIN
  select authority_id 
  into auth
  from usrr where user_id='G68EF610';
END USR_Trial;
```

I get the following error:

```
Error(2,1): PLS-00488: invalid variable declaration:  object 'USRR.DEPARTMENT' must be a type or subtype
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

If usrr.DEPARTMENT is a column in a table and you want the OUT parameter to be of the same datatype as that column then the syntax is:

```
create or replace
procedure USR_Trial
( auth out usrr.DEPARTMENT%type 
)
...
```